# Difficulty referencing theorems and enumerated items using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I’m experiencing difficulty referencing theorems and enumerated items using `hyperref`.

Here’s my minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\Thmautorefname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

The following theorem is important.

\begin{Thm} \label{Important}
Meow.
\end{Thm}

Here are some consequences of \autoref{Important}:

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(1)] \label{MM}
Meow meow.

\item[(2)] \label{MMM}
Meow meow meow.
\end{enumerate}

Let us now study the meowing coefficient of \autoref{MM}.

\end{document}
```

Now, the hyperlink for the theorem works perfectly, but the hyperlink for Item (1) doesn’t. Clicking on it directs me to the theorem instead.

Could anyone kindly resolve this issue for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forced numbering scheme removes any setting of a reference *mark*. The following example uses [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to correct that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\Thmautorefname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

The following theorem is important.

\begin{Thm} \label{Important}
Meow.
\end{Thm}

Here are some consequences of \autoref{Important}:

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
  \item \label{MM}
  Meow meow.

  \item \label{MMM}
  Meow meow meow.
\end{enumerate}

Let us now study the meowing coefficient of \autoref{MM}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Werner. Thank you so much for your response. Before I accept it, could you tell me how I may have the hyperlink read as ‘(1)’ instead of ‘item (1)’? Thanks!

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore: Don't use `\autoref`, just use `\ref`.

Comment: Just one more question, Werner. When I have an enumerated list of labeled items inside a proof environment, the hyperlink to any item doesn’t display, either inside or outside the environment. Is there anything that I can do to resolve this?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore: Can you show some example code? Perhaps using [PasteBin](//pastebin.com)?

Comment: I’m not familiar with PasteBin, but let me describe my problem precisely here. For my paper, I had to define a special proof environment using the command `\newcommand*{\Proof}{Proof}
\newenvironment{PROOF}[1][\Proof]{\begin{proof}[#1]\renewcommand*{\qedsymbol}{$ \blacksquare $}}{\end{proof}}`. Then when I created an enumerated list of labeled items between `\begin{PROOF}` and `\end{PROOF}`, and tried to refer to an item in this list within the proof environment, the hyperlink directed me to the very first theorem of my paper instead, a few pages up.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore: I can't replicate the issue with [this example](https://pastebin.com/waHUkR9R). The hyperlink jumps correctly to the first item in the `PROOF` environment.

Comment: Thank you Werner. You made me realize my mistake. Instead of letting the enumerate environment automatically generate numbers for a list, I was redundantly writing these numbers down. This somehow led to the problem that I mentioned.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore: That was your original problem as well. Time to adopt a new style. ;)